# How to accelerate CSV file reading in R

Tags: r, file, csv, fread

The root folder is `D:/data/`. Inside this root folder there are many subfolders. CSV files are stored inside subfolders, e.g.

```
D:/data/
   f1
      1.csv
      2.csv
   f2
      1.csv
      2.csv
```

I use the following code to read my CSV files. However, it takes hours to read around 20,000 CSV files.

```
allFolders = list.files("D:/data/")
for(folder in 1:length(allFolders))
{
  dirPath = paste0("D:/data/", allFolders[folder], '/')
  for(i in 1:100)
  {   
    f = fread(paste0(dirPath, i, ".csv"))
    # data processing
  }
}
```

Any idea how can I accelerate this process on Windows? I tried to use `foreach` package, however the performance was almost the same, probably, due to the speed limit of I/O device.

Update:

This is how I implement `foreach`:

```
allFolders = list.files("D:/data/")
for(folder in 1:length(allFolders))
{
  allf <- vector(mode = "list", length = 100)
  allf <- foreach(i=1:100, .combine=rbind)
  {   
    f = data.table::fread(paste0(dirPath, i, ".csv"))
    f
  }
}
```

Comment: `fread` is usually a speed demon and I suspect that's not where the bottleneck is. Can you convert the CSV files to SQLite databases (or put them as tables within one SQLite database)? Can you post the setup code for the `foreach` tries you did? It might be something in how you're doing the parallel processing config.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I doubt if SQLite would provide improvement

Comment: You should note that `fread` is from the `data.table` package. If indeed it is that `fread`. Its not in base R.

Comment: How long does it take to read one CSV file? Then figure out if its the reading or the processing or the loop that is taking the time. Then we know where to look for optimisation. Otherwise its premature optimisation.

Comment: @y0gapants it depends on where the bottleneck is. You can also force tables to be in-memory with SQLite and that may definitely speed this up.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: please see an example of my foreach code. Another problem is that that allf must be a vector of f, so that I can access elements this way allf[[i]]. But my parallel version just makes a long list of data. Which parameter should I use instead of rbind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` or `sapply` instead of a for loop might help.

To further add: 
Maybe figure out a way to clean that data up. It seems vastly inefficient to have data in 20,000 different .csv files. When I am working with large datasets (either in number of files or size) I try to clean in a number of steps, and save only the data I need in .rds files for easy reading into R.

```
allFolders = list.files("D:/data/")

folders_as_list <- lapply(1:length(allFolders), function(i){
                     dirPath <- file.path("D:/data/", allFolders[i])
                      res <- lapply(1:100, function(j){
                              f <- fread(paste0(dirPath, j, ".csv"))
                              [DATA PROCESSING]
                              return(f_processed) 
                             }) %>% rbind_all
                     return(res)
                   })
```

Which should return a list of 1:length(allFolders) where each element in the list will be a data.frame where all the individual .csv files from a single folder have been rbinded together.

Comment: Can you post an example of lapply for my case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot delete files. All of them are important. The data was initially presented that way. By the way, my question was if I can use "list.files" to get all files from subfolders?

Comment: I understand you cannot delete the files but if you are continuously working with files, it might be worth the trouble to load them into R, clean them up and combine into large `data.frames`, and then save them as .rds files. 

As for `list.files`, it takes an argument called `include.dirs` that is: "logical. Should subdirectory names be included in recursive listings? (They always are in non-recursive ones)." As well as `recursive`
"logical. Should the listing recurse into directories?"

Comment: I don't have the time to help you with an explicit solution right now, but maybe you can figure it out with an introduction to lapply at http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/